# What Are the Performance Differences Between Running One vs Many Inserts

Tags: sql, perl

I'm currently in a situation where I'm building a script that I know will need to insert multiple rows. I'm doing this in Perl, so in terms of parameterization, it's much easier to insert each row individually. In terms of speed, I'm guessing running just one insert statement will be faster (although latency will be relatively low as I'm quite close to the database itself). I'm thinking the number of rows per run of the script will be about 20-40 on average. That said, what would be the approximate performance differences between running just 1 INSERT INTO statement v.s. running one for each row? Note: The server is running SQL 2008.

[EDIT]Since there seems to be a lot of confusion, I'd like to clarify that what I'm really asking for is the theory behind how a multi-row insert is handled by SQL Server 2008. Does it essentially just convert it internally into a bunch of individual insert statements and run those over one connection, or does it do something more intelligent?

Yes, I know I can run timed loops. No, that's not what I'm asking for. [/EDIT]

Comment: Completely dependent upon your code, your hardware, your table schema, your indexes, the data in the tables, other load on the machine, etc. The only way to measure is to measure. Write some loops, test each method a few thousand times, time the tests, divide to get averages, compare.

Comment: I am not aware of what the difference would actually be, but when you are on the order of 20-40 rows as your typical insertion size I think whatever is easier to maintain and understand is worth working toward, rather than raw speed. 

That is assuming that your 20-40 insertion event is relatively infrequent as well though.

Comment: @Dan: I agree, and upvoted you for that, but I think it is worth pointing out that if you are testing each method a few thousand times to get a measurable difference, it indicates a fairly minor, and potentially insignificant optimization.

Comment: @Dan: I'm looking for theory here. There will be some underlying way in which SQL deals with insert statements and a general answer here. Obviously, to get specifics for my case, I'd run timing loops, but what I really want is a general guideline. IN GENERAL, is there a difference or no? Is there a theoretical reason for why there would be a difference?

Comment: I don't know much in the way of perl and its stack, so take this with a grain of salt... One of the biggest overheads in a 'simple' insert is actually creating the connection to the DB. if you don't have some sort of connection pool system, and you are creating and closing a new connection for each of those 40 inserts, that is a substantial amount of time that wouldn't be occurring if you had one larger insert.

Comment: @cespinoza: Your response applies to any programming language. Obviously speeds will differ depending on what operating system you're on, how much memory you have,  how fast your processor is, and 5000 other things. Nevertheless, there's still general theory that can be utilized for approximation. 

Something that's, in theory, O(n) will usually be faster in practice than something that's O(n^2), and that knowledge makes one a better coder. Yes, I could just run loops for timing on all the code I ever write, but that would be the equivalent of brute force programming. Everything has its place.

Comment: @cespinoza: Unless your middle name is Ervin :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining multiple inserts into one command is *always* going to execute **much** more quickly than executing separate inserts. The reasons are:

- A *lot* of work is done *parsing* the SQL - with multi version, there's only *one* parsing effort
- More work is done checking permissions - again, only done *once*
- Database connections are "chatty" - with multi version, handshaking only done once. You really notice this issue when using a poor network connection
- Finally, multi version gives opportunity for server to optimize the operation

Comment: Thanks! This is just the sort of answer I was looking for! Turns out if I prepare the statement, and just rerun it with different values, that's basically just as fast as running a multi-row insert (getting rid of most of the overhead you mention above). Thanks for understanding what I was asking!

Answer (score 3):

There is a general idea to let the SQL database do its thing and not try to treat the database as some sort of disk read. I've seen many times where a developer will read from one table, then another, or do a general query and then run through each row to see if it's the one they want. Generally, it's better to let the SQL database do its thing.

In this case, I can't really see an advantage of doing a single vs. multiple row insert. I guess there might be some because you don't have to do multiple prepares, and commits.

It shouldn't be too difficult to actual create a temporary database and try this out. Create a database with two columns, and have the program generate data to toss into the tables. Give yourself a decent amount to do. For example, how many items will this table have? And, how many do you think you'll be inserting at once? Say create a table of 1,000,000 items, and insert into this table 1000 items at a time, 100 items at a time, and one item at a time. Just generate data using the increment operator. There may be a "sweetspot" of the number of items you can insert at once.

In my unbiased, and always correct opinion, you'll probably find that the difference isn't worth fretting over, and you should instead employ the method that makes your code the easiest to maintain.

I've have a programming dictum: **The place where you want to optimize your code is probably the wrong place**. We like efficiency, but we usually attack the wrong item. And, whatever we've squeezed out in terms of efficiency, we end up wasting in maintenance.

So, just program what is the easiest to understand and don't fret about being overly efficient.

Comment: Good dictum. Also keep in mind Jackson's Rules of Optimization (1. Don't do it. 2. (for experts only) Don't do it yet.) and the Rules of Optimization Club ( http://perlbuzz.com/mechanix/2008/02/the-rules-of-optimization-club.html ).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a couple of other performance differentiators to think about on insertion:

- **Foreign Keys** - If the table you are inserting into has foreign keys, SQL Server effectively needs to join to the foreign key tables on insert. When you do your inserts in one query, SQL server can be more efficient in doing these joins.
- **Transactions** - As you don't mention transactions, I assume you must be using SQL Server auto-commit mode.  With such a small number of rows, it is likely that the overhead of creating 40 transactions vs. 1 transaction would be higher than maintaining the log to allow rollback. However, if you were inserting 400000 rows, it would likely be more expensive to insert in one statement/transaction than insert 400000 separate rows as the cost to be prepared to roll back up to 400000 rows is very high (if you were to insert 400000 rows, it usually is best to insert in batches -> the optimal batch size can be determined through testing). Also, above a certain row count, it may become more efficient to disable the foreign keys, insert the rows, then re-enable them.